# Pass Record ID to Related list Button (Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce

We have "Contact" object related list in "Account" object.

A list button is created in "Contact" object and added to Contact Related List in Account pagelayout.

This button calls a Screenflow to create Contact Record

Now we want to pass Account Record ID to that flow, when the button is clicked. How?